# Creating a live poll / result page

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am a graphic designer with VERY basic html/css skills. Just saying this as a precursor to my question. What I am looking to do is to create a voting poll on a website. Basically there are a bunch of videos posted and I will be putting buttons below each video that read "vote". I know how to do this aspect of what i am looking for but where my skills fall short is here - I need that "vote" button to lead to another page that will be a results page and will keep track of what video everyone voted for.

Any idea how to create this result page / live poll that will keep track of what people voted for? Any help/ assistance would be very appreciated. Thank you so much.

-M

Comment: Hi @MadelineN, you'll need a place to store the information and Javascript isn't designed to do so. You'll have to look into PHP and databases if you want to do it by yourself, or your

Answer (score 1):

> Any idea how to create this result page / live poll that will keep track of what people voted for?

Sounds like HTML/CSS won't be enough here. What you actually need to keep track of your *votes* or any data across multiple clients (users) is to use a **back-end** (server)

- Since you're already programming in JavaScript, a good candidate for your back-end is [Node.js](https://nodejs.org/en/). That will allow you to re-use your JavaScript knowledge instead of learning another programming language
- To actually **store** your votes, you will also need a **database**. You can choose any database from the major one here (MongoDB, MySQL, etc...) since all of them can do what you want
- To communicate between your front-end and back-end, use [HTTP requests](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods)

## Notes

- The link part in your front-end can be done using the `a` tag in HTML. For example `<a href='/results'>Results</a>`
- **If you don't want to build your own back-end** for any reason, look into commercial *"serverless"* products. For example [Firebase](https://firebase.google.com) which is a database that doesn't need any back-end (the back-end is actually done by the guys at Firebase/Google)

Comment: Okay, so I would prefer to not do my own backend so I will look into Firebase. So basically what this means is that I will design my page with the vote buttons and then use firebase to keep track of all the info? That will be on a completely separate page? I would like voters to be able to see how each video is being ranked in comparison.   Thank you for your help, I appreciate it!

Comment: Yes, you can use _"the same Firebase"_ on multiple pages. It will track your data (votes) and it's fairly basic to set up. Here's a [link to get started with Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup). Also don't forget to mark this as answered so other users with the same question can check it out